# How to choose transparent for fillRadialGradientColorStops of KonvaJS Rect?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ionic3, konvajs, react-konva

I'm trying to use `Konva.Rect` as overlay for image filters. When using radial gradient with transparent color stops, on IOS simulator it works perfect but on device it doesn't recognize transparent and fills it with solid color.

I tried using `transparent` and `rgba(0,0,0,0)` but the results are same. Is there any alternative thing to try?

Here is my example code;

```
          this.filterOverlay = new Konva.Rect({
            name: 'overlayRect',
            width: this.backgroundImage.width() * this.backgroundImage.scaleX(),
            height: this.backgroundImage.height() * this.backgroundImage.scaleY(),

            globalCompositeOperation: 'multiply',
            fillRadialGradientStartPoint: { x: this.backgroundImage.width()/2, y: this.backgroundImage.height()/2 },
            fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 0,

            fillRadialGradientEndPoint: { x: this.backgroundImage.width()/2, y: this.backgroundImage.height()/2 },
            fillRadialGradientEndRadius: this.backgroundImage.width()-100,
            //fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, 'transparent', 0.8, 'transparent', 1, '#222222'],
            fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 0.8, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 1, '#222222'],

          });
          this.baseLayer.add(this.filterOverlay);
          this.baseLayer.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use hex values with alpha value: `#RRGGBBAA`, did you tried it? example for you case you can use `#00000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the issue with `globalCompositeOperation: 'multiply'` on Safari v12. I can reproduce the issue on Mac (https://jsbin.com/madolohiru/1/edit?html,js,output).

As a workaround try not to use `globalCompositeOperation` or use a different value, that can give you similar filter effect.